# cannot get the length of a string through strlen in other function?

Tags: c, string, strlen

I am making a function in C which removes any duplicates form a string.
If I run this code and provide the `index` in `main()` function it works.

```
char *clean(char *list, int index) {
    int val = 0;
    char temp_list[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (list[i] != list[i + 1]) {
            temp_list[val] = list[i];
            val += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < val; y++) {
        list[y] = temp_list[y];
    }
    return list;
}
```

But if I run this code it doesn't seem to work.

```
char *clean(char *list) {
    int index = strlen(list);
    int val = 0;
    char temp_list[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (list[i] != list[i + 1]) {
            temp_list[val] = list[i];
            val += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < val; y++) {
        list[y] = temp_list[y];
    }
    return list;
}
```

In the second code the index is always zero.
Can anyone explain me why is `strlen()` function not working.

Comment: What will be `list[i + 1]` once `i` is `index-1` ? And you don't terminate your `temp_list` with `'\0'`.  In case there are no duplicates, there won't be even space for that. For completeness you should post [mcve] for both working and non-working cases.

Comment: `strlen()` works perfectly. Please show us a [example] so that we can see how you call your function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not where you think: you do not set the null terminator when reducing the length of the string, so the modified `list` still has the trailing bytes in place and reachable.

Here is a modified version without a temporary array:

```
#include <stddef.h>

char *clean(char *s) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i + 1]) {
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This will solve my problem but it may not answer my question that why doesn't strlen() work in clean() function because when I pass the string in main it will give me the needed result but if I pass the same string in clean() function then the strlen() function does not work while it has the null character at the end.

Comment: @Aditya76: the behavior should be the same for both functions. There must be another problem in the code you did not post. Can you post a full compilable example?